# Use Jagged Array In c

Tags: c, jagged-arrays

How to Insert and then  print data from jagged array in below code ?

```
int *jagged[5];

jagged[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can insert by adding a second subscript for the nested array's index.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    jagged[0][i] = some_value;
```

and print like

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", jagged[0][i]);
```

Keep in mind that you need to keep track of each nested array's length on your own. Depending on your needs, you might do something like

```
int jagged_lengths[] = {10, 5, 4, 0, 3};
int i, j;

// Write some data
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    jagged[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * jagged_lengths[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < jagged_lengths[i]; ++j)
        jagged[i][j] = some_value;
}

// Read back the data
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < jagged_lengths[i]; ++j)
        printf("%d\n", jagged[i][j]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel ! Really very helpful for me and finally i done my assignments !

Answer (score 1):

first of all, why not define your array as a multi dimentional array? unless you want the size of each member different, you don't need to use malloc for each member, simply do:

```
int jagged[5][10];
```

as for iterating, you can do something like:

```
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       jagged[i][j] = i*j; //or any value you want


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf ("%d,%d: %d\n", i, j, jagged[i][j]);
```